# Inserting tab spaces to align text vertically in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to get the following behaviour using a combination of HTML and CSS:

```
foo    = this
foobar = bit
goso   = needs
etcetc = aligning
```

Now I could just insert spaces where required (like I did above), but I'm pretty sure there must be a way to do this "automatically".

**I know I could use tables to do this, but would prefer not to.** Is there any other way of doing this?

My question boils down to this: **How do I automatically align text vertically, in a similar way to tabs in office suites, using HTML/CSS.**

Here is an in context example:

```
<p><span class="a">foo</span> <span class="b">=</span> <span class="c">"abcDeveloper"</span></p>
<p><span class="a">bar</span> <span class="b">=</span> <span class="c">"123"</span></p>
<p><span class="a">foobar</span> <span class="b">=</span> <span class="c">"dfg"</span></p>
<p><span class="a">foobarstar</span> <span class="b">=</span> <span class="c">"456"</span></p>
```

In this example, I would like text in class b to be aligned vertically.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is what tables are for.

Comment: @stark surely there must be another way though? If I'm writing something simple like an office document I do not have to create a table to align everything. I was hoping HTML/CSS had a similar solution to tabs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One method would be to apply `display: inline-block;` to your `span.a`s, and then give them a set width: http://jsfiddle.net/nzrHn/1/

```
.a { display: inline-block; width: 100px; }
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. But `width : ***` could probably help, too.

Comment: @Nico I tried that, but it does nothing. Could you explain please?

Comment: What I meant is, if you know all fields are at most 180px (for instance), then you fix the width of `span.a` to 180px and the width of `span.b` to 15px (or whatever suits you best). That way all `=` signs will be aligned, providing you with a rather ugly way of simulating a table. Still recommend a table, makes this just automatic!

Comment: Use `em` rather than `px` if you want a relative rather than an absolute unit. The former is relative to the font size and scales as the font size scales.

Answer (score 4):

Add css attribute `display: inline-block` and `min-width: XXXpx`